# What does it mean to 'traverse' a directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

What does it mean to 'traverse' a directory, for example in this description of chmod permissions?

```
r = read
w = write
x = execute (traverse for directories)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that to access to contents of a directory (traverse the directory) you need to have the execute permission for the directory.